# AuthorizationAttribute in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: authentication, cookies, authorization, .net-core

I am trying to configure cookie authentication with identity and ef. So far I am able to have a valid Set-Cookie in my Controller response. The browser sends this cookie back, but the AuthorizeFilter always redirects to Login page, thus Authentication doesn't seem to work. What am I suppoed to configure?
Here's my ConfigureServices in Startup so far:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("Cors", builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins(Configuration["AllowedOrigins"].Split(","))
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowCredentials()
                .AllowAnyHeader();
        }));

        services.AddDbContext<MyIdentityDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyIdentityDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>  {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Configuration["AuthCookieDomain"]))
            {
                options.Cookie.Domain = Configuration["AuthCookieDomain"];
            }
            options.Cookie.Name = Configuration["AuthCookieName"];
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
            options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
    }
```

Then, my Configure in Startup:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseCors("Cors");

        app.UseMvc();

        app.UseAuthentication();
    }
```

Then, my Action that actually successfully sets the cookie

```
    // GET api/values
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromBody] AuthPost post)
    {
        if (post == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(post.UserName) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(post.Password))
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(post.UserName, post.Password, true, false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        return Unauthorized();
    }
```

And finally, my other Action with Authorize attribute that does not work (Always redirects to Login)

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Get()
    {
        var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        return Ok(new { UserName = user.UserName });
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

OK, ConfigureApplicationCookie is the way to work. What caused the issue was the WRONG order of `app.UseMvc();` and `app.UseAuthentication();`

`app.UseAuthentication()` must be invoked before `app.UseMvc()`!